# TypeError:unsupported operand type[s] for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

What have I done wrong?
I'm just starting to learn python, so I do not understand much, help please.
Task: Convert degrees Fahrenheit to degrees Celsius and vice versa.
The integer degrees of Fahrenheit and Celsius are given in different lines. Print the calculated translation values on different lines.

```
Input:95_F
      73_C
```

```
a=input().split('_F')
b=input().split('_C')
a1=(5/9*(a-32))
a2=(9/5*b+32)
print (a1)
print (a2)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 3, in <module>
    a1=(5/9*(a-32))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: `split()` returns a list of strings. You're treating lists of strings as if they were numbers.

Comment: `print(b)` will show you that `b` is a `list` of `str`ings...

Answer (score 2):

`input().split()` gives you a list, and you are trying to subtract it with an `int`, hence the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`

To fix it, you want to get the first element of the list after `splitting` the string via `split`, and convert that string to an integer via `int(var)`

```
#Get the first element of the list after splitting the string, and convert that string to an integer
a=int(input().split('_F')[0])
b=int(input().split('_C')[0])

#Do the conversion
a1=(5/9*(a-32))
a2=(9/5*b+32)

#Print the temperatures
print(a1)
print(a2)
```

The output will be

```
35.0
163.4
```

Comment: Glad to help @HoujuuNue :) If the answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer. Also consider taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

split return list (element type equal string)

```
a=input().split('_F')
b=input().split('_C')

a=int(a[0])
b=int(b[0])

a1=(5/9*(a-32))
a2=(9/5*b+32)
print (a1)
print (a2)
```